# How to write XmlSerializable ReadXml for WriteXml with Elements through C# .NET v3.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm not really sure what the right question is to ask here, so I'll do my best to present the scenario.

We've got a ParentObject with a list of Quantity of various dimensions. Let's say ParentObject says it has Length, Duration, etc.

We want to serialize that to and from Xml, necessarily through WriteXml / ReadXml. I've written the WriteXml, not much problem there. Our test output shows something along these lines.

```
<ParentObject Name="SuchAndSuch">
  <Quantities>
    <Length Value="123.456" />
    <Duration Value="78.9" />
  </Quantities>
</ParentObject>
```

This is an oversimplification, of course. Point is, we're writing an element out by the name of "Quantities". That's written using WriteStartElement("Quantities") and WriteEndElement(). So far so good.

Now I am writing the ReadXml to read the thing back in and necessarily re-constitute the object. I am receiving an error something like "Element 'Quantities' not found" when I try and ReadStartElement("Quantities").

There are notes I'm studying about moving to nodes and the current node. Up to that point I've used GetAttribute() and that's it. So as far as I can tell, our reader is still at a starting position, perhaps?

Is there a better way to read through elements or otherwise position the reader so it can read our Quantites?

Thanks...

Comment: k I got the crap flamed out of me the other day for suggesting someone do it a different way yesterday so I'm going to suggest in a comment that you use the XmlSerializer class to serialize and deserialize and save yourself doing it manually unless theres a reason you need to do it this way?

Comment: okay, problem solved. Xml Elements are your friend. Everything is an Element, Element, Element, even when during your writer things don't necessarily appear to be.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question directly, but instead of writing your own code to write and read the XML, why not use **System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer** to do all the work for you?

I've only recently discovered it myself and have used it backup and restore lots of data fetched from a web service.

Example based on code I've used (Stuff = ParentObject):

```
Stuff stuff = FunctionToCreateStuff();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("stuff.xml");
x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(stuff.GetType());
x.Serialize(writer, stuff);
writer.Close();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("stuff.xml");
x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Stuff));
Stuff stuff = (Stuff)x.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Comment: this is one approach, however, we've adopted the "IXmlSerializable saves us" approach. we're implementing much of the serialization in a handful of places using Reflection to query for the members necessary for serialization.